# Selenium Web Driver to automate PaleMoon web browser?

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver, palemoon

Looking for a [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/) Web Driver to automate  [Palemoon](http://www.palemoon.org/) web browser. Googling didn't bring any results.

Comment: https://forum.palemoon.org/viewtopic.php?t=22519

Comment: @vitaliis: I see. The feature request is denied. :(